# Tkinter Canvas - Extract ROI from zoomed image

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have created an interface using Tkinter where a grayscale image is shown and I can draw a squared region of interest (ROI) on top of it with the mouse.

Using the coordinates from the ROI, I go to the image data and extract the pixels delimited by those coordinates. These pixels are then processed.

The problem is: the image is only 224x224 pixels long and it appears quite small on screen. When I need to draw a small ROI with the mouse, it is  quite imprecise.

(image + red region = 300x300 pixels. Yellow square is ROI.)

[image: smallimage]

If I rescale my image, for instance to 300x300 pixels, it becomes easier to draw the ROI. However, when Python increases the image size, it has to play a bit with pixel values and I lose the "original and perfect" information from the smaller image.

(image below is 300x300 pixels)

[image: bigimage]

Does anyone have any idea on to "zoom" the canvas so everything looks bigger and it gets easier to draw, but I still have the original 224x224 pixels?

Any ideas are welcome. Cheers!

Comment: I assume you're resizing using PIL [`Image.resize`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize). You should scale up by a whole number, with `PIL.Image.NEAREST` to minimize changes to the data. And then scale down your ROI by the same amount, so you can continue working with the original unscaled data.

Comment: Have you tried simply keeping two copies of the image, one zoomed and one not?

Comment: Thanks PM; I did not know about PIL.Image.NEAREST. It might help a bit.

Comment: Bryan Oakley, I actually don't have a way of accessing the images before hand in order to save a zoomed version. These images area extractec from a DICOM format file, a typical format for medical images which possess a bunch of other information in it.